# Project Euler Number Nine with C++

Tags: c++

I wrote this, but when running it, the console just sits at "Running..." and won't really do anything, at least that I can see.  I am kind of at a loss here as I can't think of anything else to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void) {
    int count = 0;
    do {

        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 3;
        int total;

        for (a=1;a<b;a++) {
            for (b=2;b<c;b++) {
                for (c=3;c<=1000;c++) {
                    total = a+b+c;

                    if (total == 1000 && a*a + b*b == c*c) {
                        std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c;

                    }
                }
            }
        }



        count++;

    } while(count < 1000);  
    return 0;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your command line(s) at the very least?

Comment: When I run that it just spits out numbers.

Comment: Well I am using Xcode to "Build and Run,"  do you want the debug log?

Comment: Your code seems that it will loop for 10^12 times. That will take a few days.

Comment: @Aesthete gcc which is built into Mac OSX, and is the default for Xcode.

Comment: @nhahtdh Would you mind explaining how you got that?  And also, are you saying that it will eventually give me a result?

Comment: That's right: it just loops. A lot.... are you sure that's exactly what you intended? By the way, your mention to the compiler in the question is a bit misleading.

Comment: I get `200, 375, 425375, 200, 425200, 375, 425375, 200, 425` continuously.

Comment: @DustinL.: It will terminate: at the end of the `c` loop, c = 1001 (invariant), at the end of the `b` loop, b = 1001 (invariant), so inside will loop for 10^9 times. Times the count is approx 10^12, which can be done at the day(s) scale.

Comment: @dsign Okay, I changed *compiler* to *console*.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: @nhahtdh  Thank you.  Although, I am stuck with this.  I am not sure what to do further.  Certainly open to suggestions.

Comment: The outer-most loop (`do...while (count < 1000)`) does not seem to be useful..? Nothing inside that loop actually depends on the value of `count`, or on how many times the loop was completed.

Comment: @jogojapan Well, when I used some other code with the same do...while loop, it worked fine as it stopped at 1000 iterations.

Comment: With the current code, the loop only means that the exact same thing will be repeated 1000 times. Anyway, if you add `<< std::endl` to the end of the print command in the inner-most `if` statement, you will see more output more quickly. The reason you don't see output is that the `cout` buffer is never flushed before the program comes to an end (which takes extremely long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not see any output because your terminal is line-buffered and you never write a line break or flush the stream. To fix this you could add `std::endl` to your output line:

```
std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << std::endl;
```

This way you should see all triples as soon as they are found, but the program will still take a long time to complete. It might even take a long time till *any* results are found. You could speed the program up by avoiding some of the nested loops.

Comment: Thank you!  Turns out, while this is apparently inefficient, I got the right answer!